# Creating tables with SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a table in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.

I want to create a table with columns: `category`, `customer`, `Costume`, `Payment`, and `rental`.

Here is the SQL I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CATEGORY
(
    CATEGORY_ID     CHAR(5)     PRIMARY KEY,
    CATEGORY_DESC   CHAR(50)    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.COSTUME
(
    Costume_ID              CHAR(5), 
    Costume_Desc            CHAR(50), 
    Costume_Size            CHAR(5),
    Costume_RentalPricE     DECIMAL(12,2),
    Category_ID             CHAR(5)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.CUSTOMER
(
    Customer_ID         CHAR(5),
    Customer_LastName   CHAR(50),
    Customer_FirstName  CHAR(50),
    Customer_Address    CHAR(30),
    Customer_City       CHAR(50),
    Customer_State      CHAR(2),
    Customer_Zip        CHAR(10),
    Customer_Phone      CHAR(10),
    Category_ID         CHAR(5)
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Payment
(
    Payment_ID          CHAR(5),
    Customer_ID         CHAR(5),
    Payment_Date        DATE,
    Payment_Amount      DECIMAL(12,2),
    Payment_Comment     VARCHAR,
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Rental
(
    Rental_ID       --it says this needs to be Long integer for field size?
    Customer_ID         CHAR(5),
    Costume_ID          CHAR(5),
    Rental_Date         DATE,   
    Rental_DueDate      DATE,
    Rental_CheckIn      --YES OR NO? i'M NOT SURE HOW TO DO THIS. 
    Rental_Penalty      DECIMAL(12,2)
);
```

How do I create a Boolean column and a long for fields?

Comment: Comments: I would recommand to use `INT` for your `ID` columns - and if you have more than about 5 characters, I would strongly recommend **against** using `CHAR(n)` - those strings will be padded with spaces to the defined length, e.g. even if your data is only 1 character long, 50 characters will be stored --> huge waste. Use `VARCHAR(n)` for anything longer than 5 characters!

Comment: so then using VARCHAR(n) n being 50 or however many I am using correct??

Comment: Exactly - in that case, your column can hold *up to* 50 character - but if you store only 10, then only 10 bytes (plus 2 bytes overhead) are really required. And the string stored is not padded with spaces on the end to the defined length, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
USE COSTUMERENTAL;

CREATE TABLE dbo.CATEGORY  -- should always specify schema
(
    CATEGORY_ID       CHAR(5)    PRIMARY KEY, -- can't be two data types
    CATEGORY_DESC     CHAR(50)   NOT NULL
); -- don't need to specify PRIMARY KEY twice

--USE COSTUMER RENTAL; -- is there a space in the name or not?

CREATE TABLE dbo.COSTUME
(
    Costume_ID              CHAR(5), -- need commas
    Costume_Desc            CHAR(50), 
    Costume_Size            CHAR(5),
    Costume_RentalPricE     DECIMAL(12,2), -- Number isn't a valid SQL Server data type  
    Category_ID             CHAR(5)
); -- need closing brackets; also should always use semi-colons to terminate
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create table syntax for Server Management Studio:**

In `Microsoft's SQL Server` database, create tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MYTABLE
(
    my_integer       INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, //int −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
    my_varchar       VARCHAR(100),        //strings of characters
    my_forcedwidth   CHAR(50),            //fixed width of 50 chars
    my_yes_no        BIT,                 //holds 0 or 1
    my_decimal       DECIMAL(12,2)        //precision number.
    my_bigint        Bigint               //big integer
);
```

For a full list of datatypes:  http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-data-types-reference/